# Concealing led strip light power supplies in a porch ceiling

Tags: lighting

I live in Ohio in a home built in the 50's. A very large back porch was added onto the home years later with a roof. It has the typical vinyl ceing. It has one light in the center of the ceiling controlled by a switch inside the home. I wish to remove the light and replace it with a non-lighted ceiling fan. I want to run power from the fans junction box to a separate one. My plan is to add 4 each of 12' LED tape light runs in metal channels that will be powered/switched from the switch in the house. The fan will have the pull chain to control it so when I turn the switch off in the house it will kill power to the fan and the tape lights.

Now for the meat of this post; I assume (I may be an idiot, not a complete one) I have to cut an access hole in the vinyl and add a nice looking access panel. Am I allowed, by code, to cut the plugs off of the two power supplies and hard wire them into a junction box? Do I have to screw a box in the ceiling to hide the two transformers (one for two runs) directly above the access panel or is this not allowed at all? Any and all help would be appreciated. I have to do this as cheaply and easily as possible while remaining in code. Thanks.

Comment: What make and model are the LED supplies?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have to install a receptacle face down in the ceiling and plug your devices in to that. For example, ceiling mounted projectors, garage door openers, stage lighting, all have to be plugged in to ceiling mounted receptacles. Not hard wired.

Concealing flexible cord above a ceiling is not allowed by the National Electrical Code.

> **400.8 Uses Not Permitted.** Unless specifically permitted in 400.7, flexible cords and cables shall not be used for the following:
>
> (1) As a substitute for the fixed wiring of a structure
>
> (2) Where run through holes in walls, structural ceilings, suspended ceilings, dropped ceilings, or floors
>
> (3) Where run through doorways, windows, or similar openings
>
> (4) Where attached to building surfaces
>
> *Exception to (4): Flexible cord and cable shall be permitted to be attached to building surfaces in accordance with the provisions of 368.56(B)*
>
> (5) Where concealed by walls, floors, or ceilings or located above suspended or dropped ceilings
>
> (6) Where installed in raceways, except as otherwise per-mitted in this Code
>
> (7) Where subject to physical damage

Note number 2.

There are other ways to conceal your equipment such as building a cove along a wall.

I just bought some 120volt LED rope lighting that can be much longer and doesn't need a power supply. However, you still can't run it above the ceiling.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The way to connect corded supplys in my state is to do it inside an electrical junction box or gutter (gutters are usually metal trays with removable covers) . A corded device hardwired in the access hole would not be legal.
 I thought I would expand that I was thinking power supply in the box or gutter the low voltage DC supply can then be routed to the device. If the tape lights are corded 120v I 100% agree with @archonosx

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the light junction box is ceiling fan rated,  falling fans are no fun and can ruin a weekend.☺